# How do I get BrowserSync + Gulp + Zend MVC Framework to work

Tags: php, node.js, model-view-controller, zend-framework, browser-sync

I have a website hosted to Ubuntu (and working locally on Ubuntu).

I have just started working with Gulp build system and I am a stuck for half a day trying to set up "BrowserSync".

Following [this youtube tutorial [25:00]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jgcfEhiCkG4&index=3&list=PLv1YUP7gO_viROuRcGsDCNM-FUVgMYb_G) explaining how to set BrowserSync on a NodeJS server (port 3000) - which isn't exactly my case.

Following this tutorial: https://fettblog.eu/php-browsersync-grunt-gulp/

Suggesting to use a package called "[gulp-connect-php](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-connect-php)" (which I'm not quite sure what is it doing to get the job done)

My local URL for the website is: `http://local.example.com` and the main .php file within my websites files in located inside `public/`.

This is my current `Gulpfile.js` - Which I am not sure how to set up the PHP connect task and BrowserSync:

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Required Modules 
////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var gulp         = require('gulp'),
    php          = require('gulp-connect-php'),
    uglify       = require('gulp-uglify'),
    sass         = require('gulp-ruby-sass'),
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    minifycss    = require('gulp-minify-css'),
    plumber      = require('gulp-plumber'),
    browserSync  = require('browser-sync'),
    reload       = browserSync.reload,
    concat       = require('gulp-concat'),
    rename       = require('gulp-rename');
////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// END Required Modules 
////////////////////////////////////////////////////


////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// HTML Task - When HTML changes - update the bowser
////////////////////////////////////////////////////
gulp.task('html', function(){
    gulp.src([
        'application/modules/**/*.phtml', 
        'application/modules/**/**/*.phtml', 
        'application/modules/**/**/**/*.phtml', 
        'application/modules/**/**/**/**/*.phtml', 
        ]);
});

////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// END HTML Task 
////////////////////////////////////////////////////


////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Styles Task 
////////////////////////////////////////////////////
gulp.task('styles', function() {
  return gulp.src([
          'public/static/rcss/bootstrap.min.css',
          'public/static/rcss/style.css',
          'public/static/rcss/responsive.css',
          'public/static/rcss/font-awesome.min.css',
          'public/static/rcss/yamm.css'
        ])
    .pipe( plumber() )
    // .pipe(sass({ style: 'expanded' })) // Don't have SASS here.
    // .pipe(autoprefixer({ // Currently doesn't work - will work with SASS if installed in the future.  
    //  browsers: ['last 4 version']
    // }))
    .pipe( gulp.dest('public/static/rcss/finalCSS') )
    .pipe( rename( {suffix: '.min'} ) )
    .pipe( minifycss() )
    // .pipe(uglify()) // ^ same as minifycss() actually...
    .pipe( concat('all.min.js') )
    .pipe( gulp.dest('public/static/rcss/finalCSS') )
    .pipe( reload( { stream: true } ) );
});
////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// END Styles Task 
////////////////////////////////////////////////////


////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// PHP Connect Task
////////////////////////////////////////////////////
gulp.task('php', function() {
    php.server({ 
        base: 'public', 
        port: 8010, 
        keepalive: true
    });
});
////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// END  Task 
////////////////////////////////////////////////////


////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Browser-Synd Task 
////////////////////////////////////////////////////
gulp.task('browser-sync',['php'], function() {
    browserSync({
        proxy: '127.0.0.1:8010',
        port: 8080,
        open: true,
        notify: false
    });
});
////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// END Browser-Synd Task 
////////////////////////////////////////////////////


////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Scripts  Task 
////////////////////////////////////////////////////
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    /*gulp.src([''])
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(''));*/ 
});
////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// END Scripts Task 
////////////////////////////////////////////////////


////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Watch Task 
////////////////////////////////////////////////////
gulp.task('watch', function(){
    // Listen to CSS changes:
    gulp.watch('public/static/rcss/*.css', ['styles']);
    // Listen to Javascript code changes:
    gulp.watch('public/static/*.js', ['scripts']);
    // Listen to HTML changes:
    gulp.watch('application/modules/**/*.phtml', ['html']);
    gulp.watch('application/modules/**/**/*.phtml', ['html']);
    gulp.watch('application/modules/**/**/**/*.phtml', ['html']);
    gulp.watch('application/modules/**/**/**/**/*.phtml', ['html']);
    // Listem to index.php 
    gulp.watch(['public/*.php'], [reload]);
});
////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// END Watch Task 
////////////////////////////////////////////////////


////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Default Task 
////////////////////////////////////////////////////
gulp.task( 'default', [ 'scripts', 'styles', 'html', 'browser-sync', 'watch'] );
////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// END Default Task 
////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

When running in the terminal `gulp`, I get an error message pointing on `php = require('gulp-connect-php'),` - commenting it out get't all the rest working with no problem.

```
myubuntuuser@myubuntuuser-874X:/var/www/example$ gulp
/var/www/example/node_modules/gulp-connect-php/index.js:16
    [...arguments].forEach((x) => { this[x] = Symbol(x) });
     ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/example/gulpfile.js:5:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
```

Comment: What's your node version?

Comment: `myubuntuuser@myubuntuuser-124X:/var/www/example$ node -v
v4.2.6`

Comment: Node 6 is the current stable version. I'll bet `gulp-connect-php` is using some modern ES stuff that Node 4 doesn't support. Try bumping your node version.

Comment: @ceejayoz I am exactly trying to figure how to update node 4.2.6 to 6.. But while I'm doing that I came across this post please tell me what does this meen :X https://github.com/micahblu/gulp-connect-php/issues/42

Comment: @ceejayoz I did actually stop getting this error message after updating to node v6.10.3 following the first method in this URL: http://www.hostingadvice.com/how-to/update-node-js-latest-version/

So thanks a lot! :) 
The thing is when typing `node -v` i get `6.10.3` and when i use `nodejs -v` i get `4.2.6` again. aren't they the same? :S

Comment: @ceejayoz I don't get CSS or HTML updated directly on the page btw

Comment: `nodejs` is the `apt-get` package for Ubuntu (there was already a package called `node` so they used a different name). `node` is the new version you installed. You can likely safely `apt-get uninstall nodejs`.

Comment: you mean `apt-get remove nodejs` ;) Thanks a lot!